# How to trigger `undefined is not a function` in modern broswers?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I remember getting this error a lot a while before. Today I wanted to show it to a friend unfamiliar with Javascript. Chrome and Safari instead gave me something like:

```js
> const o = {};
< undefined
> o.doge()
< TypeError: o.doge is not a function (In 'o.doge()',' 'o.doge' is undefined)
```

Chrome and Firefox seem to be user-friendly as well.

How can I get an original error, without this helpful message?

Comment: Try    undefined()

Comment: This works, yes, but is very artificial and doesn't explain why `undefined is not a function` is such a famous thing.

Comment: well, looks likethis is finally throwing useful errors (I could swear it wasn't that way the last time I had that) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never get that error in a modern browser; the error comes from js engine itself not the browser; and if there are no others other than that `Type Error`, modern engines will return a more developer friendly error by applying a (similar) `/(w+)/` regex on what ever typed before `()` and placing it in the error message check out:

[v8 (chrome) message templates](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/message-template.h)  that will make the error string (line 51, 52):

```cpp
T(CalledNonCallable, "% is not a function")
```

and  [SpiderMoneky (mozilla) message templates](https://github.com/dumganhar/SpiderMonkey/blob/8d84abf624478e8a2f5e4723ac49906abfee4a1f/js/src/js.msg) (at line 51, 54):

```cpp
MSG_DEF(JSMSG_NOT_FUNCTION,            1, JSEXN_TYPEERR, "{0} is not a function")
```

[non-callable test case in v8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/test/message/fail/call-primitive-function.out) and a  [SpiderMokney test case](https://github.com/dumganhar/SpiderMonkey/blob/8d84abf624478e8a2f5e4723ac49906abfee4a1f/js/src/tests/js1_5/Regress/regress-355556.js) .

---

So the only way to a `undefined is not a function` error message in a modern browser is doing `undefined()` :)

```js
undefined()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just try to find and download an older version of the browser which logged the `original` error. (if that version is still publicly available).